# Опять про кодировку и mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Прочел пару-тройку статей, сделал, как люди советуют в них, но вопросики как отображались, так и отображаются. Почему?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй на каждый параметр в таблице установить котировку UTF-8 Unicode.

Comment: Установил - не помогло! Поля надеюсь alert-тить с этой же кодировкой не надо?

Comment: А вы пробовали добавить запись заново? Просто если изменить котировку в базе, то поля которые там были, не изменяться. Да кстати, попробуйте изменить кодировка на UTF-8 в файле обработчика.

Comment: Вот!!! Вот именно второй комментарий Ваш помог! Нужно было именно ДОБАВИТЬ новую запись! Спасибо, дружище!!!

Comment: Да не за что) Вам мой совет, если дали ответ, то тестируйте его полностью. Не забудьте поставить галочку ;)